# Wordpress Google App Engine Cloud Sql always On

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I just deployed a wordpress website in GAE. I have activated the GAE plugin and batcache. Right now, even when nobody is using the connection, **it seems to show one active connection to the cloudsql instance.**

I would like to minimize my cost. My website will have at most 100-150 users per day , and I would like to make it as cheap as possible.

How do I use the CLOUD SQL at less as possible ? My website will have mostly static content , with a few updates a few times in a month.

Comment: you don't really have much choice in the matter I think unless there are configuration options to change or you want to start editing the source code.

Comment: without anybody visiting, I will be charged ?

Comment: you pay per unit time or per whole day for the SQL, so yes, of course you'll be charged IF that connection keeps the SQL server running. The SQL server does shut itself down after a period of inactivity however.

Comment: is it possible for me to specify that period ?

Comment: If your instance is billed per use, then you will be charged for just the time that your database is up, rounded up to the nearest hour. By default, your instance is spun up whenever you access it (whether from a SQL prompt, an external application, or from an App Engine application), and remains up for 15 minutes after the completion of the last access. After this time, the instance is shut down. You will not be charged for the time your database is not up. 

Note that an instance stays up as long as there are clients connected to it. This includes idle connections.

Comment: don't think so, no. https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#how_usage_calculated

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679370/cloudsql-monitoring-usage 
I want to know how to monitor my costs

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOURPROJECTNAME/billing/unbilledinvoice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67805/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-paul-collingwood).