# CloudSql monitoring usage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just made a cloudsql instance , along with an app engine website, and because it is in its initial stages, I would like to closely monitor the cloudsql usage and how much I am getting charged from it.

Where in the developers section is this option available? I would like to have a detailed view of my cost,instance hours, etc. The graphs in the overview section just provide the connection details, but I would also like to know how to find out current costs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get daily updates from site

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project>/billing/unbilledinvoice
```

where `<project>` is the name of your project.  However, I don't know if there's a way to monitor more closely than a "daily" basis.

Comment: i am using the 60 day trial, and its blank. I would want to get price estimates before switching to paid